# XCode crashes whenever i add Files to the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

Whenever i add files to my libraries folder xcode crashes immediately without adding the files actually :/

I am currently working on a react-native project and when ever i manually want to add a third party project into my project it crashes...

Any ideas how to handle this? I tried deleting all DS_Store files which i have read in some posts, but without success. (`sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;`)

Comment: What version of xcode do you use?

Comment: I am working on the newest version. But i found a way to fix it. I had to unlink all modules then remove all libraries by hand and re-import them. Then ran react-native link and everything was fine again. Thanks though :)

Comment: @BigPun86 thanks for the tip. was facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

turn off source control. i ran into this issue and asked for help. worked for me. https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/6zevbt/xcode_crashes_whenever_i_add_files_to_a_project/

Answer (score 1):

try updating your xcode it will work it happened to me once or twice

Comment: See above comment :) But thanks, it works now again ;)

Answer (score 0):

It crashed because I was trying to add a file to blue "group with folder" (it was already there)